# Pull 14 Records From One List to Another

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following lists created below. The rsiCalcList is already populated with what I want but I need to pull the first 15 skipping the first item from rsiCalcList to firstRSICalculationHistInfo. I have also attached my attempt that comes up with an error. I have also attached the error below. Some guidance on how I could achieve my goal

```
private class rsiCalcList
{
    public string rsiCalcSymbol { get; set; }
    public DateTime rsiCalcDate { get; set; }
    public decimal rsiCalcCloseChange { get; set; }
}

private class firstRSICalculationHistInfo
{
    public string firstRSISymbol { get; set; }
    public DateTime firstRSICalcDate { get; set; }
    public decimal firstRSICloseChange { get; set; }
}

irstRSIHistInfo = rsiCalcList
     .Select(x => new firstRSICalculationHistInfo { firstRSISymbol = x.rsiCalcSymbol, firstRSICalcDate = x.rsiCalcDate, firstRSICloseChange = x.rsiCalcCloseChange })
     .OrderBy(x => x.firstRSICloseChange)
     .Skip(1)
     .Take(15);
```

### Error

```
Error   CS0266  Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<AfterTrade.RelativeStrengthIndex.firstRSICalculationHistInfo>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<AfterTrade.RelativeStrengthIndex.firstRSICalculationHistInfo>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)   AfterTrade  C:\Users\\Documents\Projects\Stockton\Development\AfterTrade\RelativeStrengthIndex.cs   86  Active
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Resolve your query with `.ToList()`.

```
irstRSIHistInfo = rsiCalcList
     .Select(x => new firstRSICalculationHistInfo { firstRSISymbol = x.rsiCalcSymbol, firstRSICalcDate = x.rsiCalcDate, firstRSICloseChange = x.rsiCalcCloseChange })
     .OrderBy(x => x.firstRSICloseChange)
     .Skip(1)
     .Take(15)
     .ToList();
```

Comment: Well that hurts my feelings a bit being so close.  I will mark this as answer when I can.  Thank you.

Comment: No reason for any hurt feelings.  It was a well-articulated question and an easy thing to miss.  Happy to help!

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see, your Linq is valid. However, .Take() returns an IEnumerable. It seems that `irstRSIHistInfo` is of type List. So, add .ToList() to the end of your Linq statement.